# Как правильно прибиндить коллекцию к DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я точно знаю, как это делается в WPF+MVVM через реализацию `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Но вот с `WinForms` я застрял и потерпел поражение.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы не трогать `DataSource` у таблицы в процессе выполнения кода, а максимум на этапе инициализации. Но у меня не получилось реализовать это через `dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", ItemsList, nameof(ItemsList))`, ловлю исключение, говорящее о том, что так нельзя.

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the property or column ItemsList on the DataSource.
Parameter name: dataMember'
```

Гуглил, читал англоязычные доки, но меня это не спасло.

В результате я сдался, и сделал вот так.

```csharp
private BindingList<MyClass> _itemsList;

public BindingList<MyClass> ItemsList
{
    get => _itemsList;
    set
    {
        _itemsList = value; 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ItemsList;
    }
}
```

**А как это делают опытные WinForms разработчики?** В смысле не бизнес-логику, а техническую реализацию, чтобы можно было писать в свойство, а табличка перезагружала бы данные из источника сама? Вдруг я что-то упустил.

Сразу оговорюсь, в шаблоне **MVP** у меня опыта ноль, и сейчас приложение напоминает классическую мешанину из обработчиков событий в классах типа `Form`. Но есть план сделать по-взрослому, вот и ищу потенциальные методики взаимодействия с интерфейсом, чтобы, как говорят грамотные люди: "отделить логику от представления".

*Мигрировать проект на WPF буду, но не сейчас, а скорее после стабильного релиза .NET 5. А сейчас просто хочется причесать древний код, повыкидывать костыли, чтобы миграция потом не превратилась в написание проекта с нуля.*

Comment: Мне кажется перенести проект на WPF сейчас будет более оптимальным решением, чем ждать выхода .NET 5. Перенос WinForms на WPF это как не крути большой объем работы, где скорей всего больше половины кода нужно будет переписывать. А вот обновить проект с .NET 4.7/4.8 до 5 версии куда проще. Так что вы уверены, что данный "геморой" вам нужен сейчас? Ибо как по мне, это лишняя работа. Пишите уж сразу на чистовик.

Comment: Привязка к таким свойствам у меня работает. Если вы можете сделать простой проект демонстрирующий проблему и выложить на гитхаб, я посмотрю что не так. Есть опыт с WinForms data binding.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вы правы, но с ответом ниже я легко перепишу это на MVVM прямо в WinForms, и для миграции в WPF надо будет только разметить интерфейс. Часть бизнес-логики уже уехала в VM. Сейчас мне надо рубить дрова, и WinForms здесь - вполне подходящий топор. Я не пишу новых фичей, я неспеша ракладываю костыли по полочкам и правлю баги, как раз чтобы потом миграция состоялась. Сейчас она невозможна без переписывания с нуля.

Comment: Двойная работа ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Третьим параметром привязки идёт имя свойства источника данных, а не имя самого источника.

В каком классе расположено свойство `ItemsList`? Судя по тому, что идёт прямое обращение к датагриду, оно расположено в классе формы.

Тогда привязку следует делать так:

```
dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", this, nameof(ItemsList));
```

Где `this` - указатель на форму (или, в общем случае, на экземпляр класса, содержащего свойство `ItemsList`).

В сеттере, естественно, при этом не должно быть `dataGridView1.DataSource = ItemsList;`

---

Несколько смущает, что `ItemsList` является публичным свойством. Значит, в любой момент может быть присвоен новый `BindingList<MyClass>` откуда-то извне. При этом нужно сделать повторную привязку. А перед этим удалить предыдущую. И за всем этим должен следить тот, кто извне задаёт это свойство...

---

С учётом всего этого, вариант сеттера с заданием привязки является гораздо более простым и правильным.

---

Мне не нравятся названия наподобие `ItemsList`, `UserCollection` и т. п. Ведь это венгерская нотация в худшем её проявлении. Только вместо префикса - суффикс типа. Я бы писал просто `Items`, `Users` и т. п.

Comment: Все заработало с реализацией `INotifyPropertyChanged`, ошибка действительно была в аргументах `DataGridView.DataBindings.Add()`. Спасибо большое!